# CRUD : How to delete a product category with all products inside?

Tags: javascript, express, backend, crud

I need to delete a product category, with all products inside. In Product model, category is an object reference.

Is there a simple way, some known method ?
I tried removeAll, it says removeAll is not a function.

```js
router.delete(`/category/:id/delete`, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.params.id) res.send("missing id");
    else {
      await Product.removeAll({ category: req.params.id });

      const categoryToDelete = await Category.findById(req.params.id);
      await categoryToDelete.remove();

      res.send("category deleted");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});
```

thanks for your knowledge and help

Comment: What is Product ? And what is Category ? You should give more clue about the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
router.delete(`/category/:id/delete`, async (req, res) => {
try {
  if (!req.params.id) res.send("missing id");
  else {

    await Product.remove({ category: req.params.id });

    res.send("category deleted");
  }
 }
  } catch (error) {
     res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});
```

simply pass the query into the remove method, this will remove all matching documents

Comment: Oh ! so simple !! I was thinking .remove was only deleting one object at a time.
Thank you very much, I feel dumb but relieved :)